# Seeking shapefiles of global climate/climatic zones

Tags: data, climate

Have been looking around a bit for a shapefile/kml/etc file of global climatic zones (as listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_zone) -- temperature, subtropical, tropical, etcetera.

Also would be very pleased to find gis overlays detailing photoperiod areas, that sort of thing?

An online GIS service would be fine for this as well for this, as long as its a real GIS with aerial overlays etc, not a plane paper PDF deal, which is about all I can find.

One promising (but dead link) source I found before posting question: https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/usclimdivs/boundaries.html

Comment: I think this would be more on-topic at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Right, and there is a recent related question with answer(s): https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/16113/georeferenced-k%c3%b6ppen-climate-classification-maps

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A respected source of global climate classification information can be found here: http://koeppen-geiger.vu-wien.ac.at/present.htm. The data are in KMZ rather than shapefile format, but should be easy to convert. The value of using these is that the methodology for their creation is well documented (see citations [here](http://koeppen-geiger.vu-wien.ac.at/)).

Answer (score 2):

I have generated a shapefile from the raster mentioned above. I simply used the "Raster to Vector" tool in QGIS.

You may decide to create the shapefile by yourself or simply download it from my website here: https://geoafrikana.com/resources/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.gloh2o.org/koppen/

They have projections for climate change as well. Interesting and relatively high resolution.