# Looking for high quality Koppen climate maps

Tags: data, climate

I wonder if anyone can point me in the direction of high resolution Koppen climate maps for use in academic research. I want to accurately place c. 100 study sites from around the world in their respective climatic zones for a meta analysis I am conducting.

Comment: Could the answer by @malizia to this question [Where can I find some shapefiles of global climate/climatic zones](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247391/where-can-i-find-some-shapefiles-of-global-climate-climatic-zones) be of help?

Comment: thanks very much! - I had already found some data that these guys supply n ready to use GIS format, but it wasnt a high enough resolution. From the answer in the thread you  have linked me to I see that it must be possible to use the KMZ/ google earth data format somehow...I will look into that now! Thanks again.

Comment: If you are ever seeking open data the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.